# Using radar/polar graphs to depict individual datapoints

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, visualization, radar-chart

This is following my previous post: [How to measure the area of a polygon in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47644156/how-to-measure-the-area-of-a-polygon-in-ggplot2)

What I would like now to do is to use the resulting radar charts as data points in a totally separate scatterplot or maybe save the object and use it later on graphs to depict the shape of the actual data.

I have many files and they typically look like this. They range from 1 to many in col number and the fractions are always in descending format. ie #1 always contributes most in any given file.

```
myfile
01 0.31707317
02 0.12195122
03 0.09756098
04 0.07317073
05 0.07317073
06 0.07317073
07 0.07317073
08 0.07317073
09 0.04878049
10 0.04878049
```

Here, I would like to plot a radar chart for each of these files individually and just get the shape with no grid around it. ggradar is the closest and the nicest I have found.

```
ggradar(as.matrix(t(radar)), group.point.size = 2, grid.line.width = 0, grid.max = 1.0, grid.mid = 0, 
    grid.min = 0, axis.line.colour = "white", axis.label.size = 0, grid.label.size = 0, 
    centre.y = 0, background.circle.colour = "white", group.colours = "black", group.line.width = 1)
```

[image: radargraph]

Now the problem starts when I want to use these shapes as data points.

@brian kindly commented and hinted as to how to approach this.

[R::ggplot2::geom_points: how to swap points with pie charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984614/rggplot2geom-points-how-to-swap-points-with-pie-charts/44125392#44125392)

[Small ggplot2 plots placed on coordinates on a ggmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45411140/small-ggplot2-plots-placed-on-coordinates-on-a-ggmap/45417727#45417727)

Inspired by these comments, I can now save plots as one column along with the filename and keep adding the new files using the same pipeline.

```
  for (file in file_list){
#eliminate the empty files (they contain only the header)
if (file.size(file) > 420){
  # if the merged dataset does exist, append to it
  if (exists("dfradar")){
    radarfile <-read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
    radarfile1 <- as.data.frame(as.numeric(radarfile[,3]))
    rownames(radarfile1) <- c(1:nrow(radarfile))
    dfradar1 <- ggradar(t(radarfile1), group.point.size = 1, grid.line.width = 0, grid.max = 1, grid.mid = 0, 
                        grid.min = 0, axis.line.colour = "white", axis.label.size = 0, grid.label.size = 0, 
                        centre.y = 0, background.circle.colour = "white", group.colours = "black", group.line.width = 0.5) + 
                    theme(legend.position = "none")      
    dfradar1 <- cbind(substring(file,11), dfradar1)
    dfradar <- rbind(dfradar, dfradar1)
  }  
  # if the merged dataset doesn't exist, create it
  if (!exists("dfradar")){
    radarfile <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
    radarfile1 <- as.data.frame(as.numeric(radarfile[,3]))
    rownames(radarfile1) <- c(1:nrow(radarfile))
    dfradar <- ggradar(t(radarfile1), group.point.size = 1, grid.line.width = 0, grid.max = 1, grid.mid = 0, 
                        grid.min = 0, axis.line.colour = "white", axis.label.size = 0, grid.label.size = 0, 
                        centre.y = 0, background.circle.colour = "white", group.colours = "black", group.line.width = 0.5) + 
                theme(legend.position = "none")
    dfradar <- cbind(substring(file,11), dfradar)
    rm(radarfile)
    rm(radarfile1)
  }
} }
```

Now when I want to save the grobs, I can't; I get:

> "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: attempt to
>   apply non-function."

or:

> "Error in plot_clone(plot) : attempt to apply non-function"

```
# merge the df with another df containing all other 
# variables that I wanna use in my scatterplot
dfradar_merge <- merge(dfradar, Cases, all=FALSE)
dfradar_merge <-  dfradar_merge %>% mutate(radargrobs = list(annotation_custom(ggplotGrob(radarplots)), 
xmin = as.numeric(Gender), xmax = as.numeric(Gender)*1.2, 
ymin = as.numeric(Age) , ymax = as.numeric(Age)*1.2)))
```

I think if I can get this part straight and pass the variables as xmin and ymin, I should be able to do what I need...

Any ideas are really appreciated. It has been a headache for me.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with the following idea. I used the ggradar package to create a graphic. Then, I looked into the data frames staying behind the graphic with `ggplot_build()`. It seems that there are 13 lists behind the graphic. I needed to investigate which list is the right one containing polygon data. I found that the 6th list is the one you want to extract and save for your future use. Let me show you what I have done.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggradar)
library(scales)

# I modified the code from https://github.com/ricardo-bion/ggradar to get a graphic.

mtcars %>%
mutate_all(rescale) %>%
mutate(group = rownames(mtcars)) %>%
slice(5:9) %>%
select(1:4) -> mtcars_radar

g <- ggradar(mtcars_radar)
```

The code above generates the following graphic. There is something wrong with my computer or something else, and I do not see a complete graphic. But this is not an issue for this question.

[image]

Now, we want to get the data staying behind the graphic and look for the right data.

```
foo <- ggplot_build(g)$data

# This is the 6th list in foo.

 $ :'data.frame':   20 obs. of  8 variables:
  ..$ colour  : chr [1:20] "#FF5A5F" "#FF5A5F" "#FF5A5F" "#FF5A5F" ...
  ..$ x       : num [1:20] 0 0.72 -0.687 0 0 ...
  ..$ y       : num [1:20] 1.111 -0.416 -0.397 1.111 0.611 ...
  ..$ group   : atomic [1:20] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
  .. ..- attr(*, "n")= int 5
  ..$ PANEL   : Factor w/ 1 level "1": 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ size    : num [1:20] 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 ...
  ..$ linetype: num [1:20] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  ..$ alpha   : logi [1:20] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

You want to extract this list as a data frame. The reason why I could spot this list is that I was paying attention to color information (e.g., `FF5A5F`).

```
mydf <- foo[[6]]

    colour          x          y group PANEL size linetype alpha
1  #FF5A5F  0.0000000  1.1111111     1     1  1.5        1    NA
2  #FF5A5F  0.7203077 -0.4158698     1     1  1.5        1    NA
3  #FF5A5F -0.6868360 -0.3965450     1     1  1.5        1    NA
4  #FF5A5F  0.0000000  1.1111111     1     1  1.5        1    NA
5  #FFB400  0.0000000  0.6111111     2     1  1.5        1    NA
6  #FFB400  0.4286803 -0.2474987     2     1  1.5        1    NA
7  #FFB400 -0.2584135 -0.1491951     2     1  1.5        1    NA
8  #FFB400  0.0000000  0.6111111     2     1  1.5        1    NA
9  #007A87  0.0000000  1.1111111     3     1  1.5        1    NA
10 #007A87  0.7203077 -0.4158698     3     1  1.5        1    NA
11 #007A87 -0.4726248 -0.2728700     3     1  1.5        1    NA
12 #007A87  0.0000000  1.1111111     3     1  1.5        1    NA
13 #8CE071  0.0000000  0.1111111     4     1  1.5        1    NA
14 #8CE071  0.2467912 -0.1424850     4     1  1.5        1    NA
15 #8CE071 -0.2278119 -0.1315273     4     1  1.5        1    NA
16 #8CE071  0.0000000  0.1111111     4     1  1.5        1    NA
17 #7B0051  0.0000000  0.1111111     5     1  1.5        1    NA
18 #7B0051  0.2595364 -0.1498434     5     1  1.5        1    NA
19 #7B0051 -0.1268266 -0.0732234     5     1  1.5        1    NA
20 #7B0051  0.0000000  0.1111111     5     1  1.5        1    NA
```

Let's confirm if this data reproduces the five triangles in the ggradar graphic.

```
gg <- ggplot(data = mydf, aes(x = x, y = y, group = group, color = factor(group))) +
      geom_path(show.legend = FALSE) +
      theme_bw()
```

[image]

In summary, you want to hack ggplot data to extract the data you want. This method allows you to save data for the "shape" that you want. I hope this is what you are after.